# About intellij-idea, how can I back to the previous code after I changed it?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm starting to use intellij-idea in few days , not like visual studio , when I changed the code , I can still go back if i'm not content with it , does intellij-idea have this function ? How can I find it ?

Comment: It's nothing like visual studio -- it's much better in every respect. Like any professional software, you can expect to take a while to learn how to use it effectively, but it's well worth the effort. Pro-tip: Always use maven with your java projects and always load the project from the pom in intellij.

Comment: I agree with you , its very effectively , i will try what you said , thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You can use any version control for that. If you don't have any VCS enabled for the project, use [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-local-history.html).